# validation keeps working from deleted rows in a dynamic form in Antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm following the docs of Antd and tried to use this piece of code from here [antd dynamic form item](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-dynamic-form-items):

```
import { Form, Input, Button, Space } from 'antd';
import { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log('Received values of form:', values);
  };

  return (
    <Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
          <>
            {fields.map(field => (
              <Space key={field.key} style={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: 8 }} align="baseline">
                <Form.Item
                  {...field}
                  name={[field.name, 'first']}
                  fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'first']}
                  rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing first name' }]}
                >
                  <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item
                  {...field}
                  name={[field.name, 'last']}
                  fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'last']}
                  rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing last name' }]}
                >
                  <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                </Form.Item>
                <MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => remove(field.name)} />
              </Space>
            ))}
            <Form.Item>
              <Button type="dashed" onClick={() => add()} block icon={<PlusOutlined />}>
                Add field
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </>
        )}
      </Form.List>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

But I have this error, when I add some rows, then delete some of them and finally submit, the validator keeps working even after I had deleted those rows.

[image]

Here is a demo that replicates my error.
https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-ride-m1pe6?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug from antd.

An issue was opened about that on their github.
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/27576

And the associate PR :
https://github.com/react-component/field-form/pull/213

A fix has been merged last week. Normally, the next release will include the fix.